# database inner join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch crimes from `crm_ms_fir` table where condition should be based on category of crime database detail →

```
crm_ms_fir(fir_id,crime_id)
crm_ms_crime(crime_id,crime_category_id,crime_name)
crm_ms_category(category_id,category_name)
```

Example: give me all `fir` reports where crime came under `crime_category_id = 2`

```
SELECT fir.fir_id,
       fir.crime_id,
       crm.crime_name
  FROM crm_ms_fir fir
 INNER JOIN crm_ms_crime crm
 INNER JOIN crm_ms_crime_category
    ON crm.category_id=3
```

This the sample query which I have written .

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: brother em using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the JOIN conditions, and crm_ms_category is not needed here.

```
SELECT fir.fir_id, fir.crime_id, crm.crime_name
FROM crm_ms_fir fir
  INNER JOIN crm_ms_crime crm ON fir.crime_id = crm.crime_id
WHERE crm.category_id=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to join `crm_ms_crime_category` because you have category_id in `crm_ms_crime` and don't use anything from `crm_ms_crime_category`. Also ON condition is missed. So try simply this:

```
SELECT fir.fir_id, fir.crime_id, crm.crime_name
FROM crm_ms_fir fir
INNER JOIN crm_ms_crime crm ON fir.crime_id = crm.crime_id
WHERE crm.category_id=3
```